# SIGSEGV(signal 11) 'segmentation fault' in FCTRL2 codechef

Tags: c++, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

I am facing SIGSEGV error on submitting [solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/6379995) for codechef small factorial problem code **[FCTRL2](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2/)** though the code works fine on **ideone**
coding language **C++ 4.3.2**
Example
Sample input:
4
1
2
5
3
Sample output:
1
2
120
6

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fact(int n) {
    int m = 1, a[200];
    for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
        a[j] = 0;
    }

    a[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            a[j] = (a[j] * i) + temp;
            temp = a[j] / 10;
            a[j] %= 10;
            if (temp > 0) {
                m++;
            }
        }

    }
    if (a[m - 1] == 0) {
        m -= 1;
    }
    for (int l = m - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
        cout << a[l];
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    while (i--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        fact(n);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is probably wrong: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` indexing starts at `0` and ends with `size - 1`.

Comment: I tried your code and it gives wrong result with 6 already.

Comment: "the code works fine on ideone coding language C++ 4.3.2".  Are you sure? Try it with some sample input using **BIG** factorials.  E.g. the very simple input 1st line = `1`, second line = `100`.  It seems to fail on any input value greater than 25

Comment: By the way - you should edit the question to show the input and output for a run that works and one that fails.  Also it might have been useful to explain why you were using the array `a` (to perform multiplication digit by digit in base 10 because factorial (100) would overflow available basic C++ types)

Answer (score 1):

(*Erased code computing a factorial using int*)

The problem in your code is that you increment m each time `temp` is not 0 for each digit multiplication. You may then get a SIGSEGV when computing big factorials because `m` becomes too big. You probably saw it because 0 shows up in front of your result. I guess this is why you added the

```
if (a[m - 1] == 0) {
    m -= 1;
}
```

You should only increment `m` when the inside loop is finished and term is not null. Once fixed you can get rid of the above code.

```
void fact(int n) {
    int m = 1, a[200];
    for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
        a[j] = 0;
    }

    a[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            a[j] = (a[j] * i) + temp;
            temp = a[j] / 10;
            a[j] %= 10;
        }
        // if (temp > 0) {
        //    a[m++] = temp;
        // }
        while (temp > 0)
        {
            a[m++] = temp%10;
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }
    for (int l = m - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
        cout << a[l];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work to compute a `n` > 12 or so with a 32 bit `int`.  Whilst not a great SO question - the OP links to a brief which says it should cope with factorials up to 100 (521 bits).  In all likelihood it fails because of the way the OP is trying to handle numbers that would overflow `int`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I overlooked that. I updated my answer and fixed his code.

Comment: Corrected the fault u mentioned works correctly on ideone now but at codechef its treated as a [wrong anwser](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/6381338)

Comment: You are not debugging your code carefully.  That's why I didn't just fix it up when I identified the problem.  Try an input of 40 to your (new) code. @chmike - your re-implementation is still broken.  If my comments and suggestions how to debug help - feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: @ J Richard Snape You are right. temp can be bigger than 9 when leaving the internal loop. So the handling of temp after the loop is not correct. I've fixed the code.

Comment: I now get the same result for fact(100) shown here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44226/bc-doesnt-support-log-and-factorial-calculation

Comment: In fact I get the same output with the commented code. It's just that a[m-1] contains a value bigger then 9. When printing  ̀a` in reverse order, the output is same as when using the while loop to isolate the digits. So I don't see any error in my code.

Comment: Just to make my position clear - the code as now written works perfectly.  I took off the downvote when the first edit was made.  Sorry I missed the second edit - now upvoted.  However, for clarity, I get entirely the wrong answer if you remove the `while` loop and put the comented code back in.  Your solution now is the one I was trying to hint at in my answer.  Sorry it took a while to reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat** I'm not going to just fix up your code for you straight up, but I will highlight where it's going wrong and why you get the seg fault.

---

Your problem is with your implementation of how you're trying to handle the digit by digit multiplication - specifically with what happens to your `m` value.  Test it out by outputting `m` each time it's incremented - you'll find it's incrementing more often than you intend.  You're right to realise you need to use an approach to get to 158 digits and your basic concept could be made to work.

The first clue is by testing with `n = 6` when you get a leading `0` that you shouldn't even though you try to get rid of that problem with the `if` block that contains `m-=1`

Try with `n = 25` and you will see a *lot* of leading zeros.

Any value greater than this will fail with a Segmentation error. The Seg fault is because, with this error, you try to set values of the array `a` beyond the max index (as `m` gets greater than `200`)

**N.B.** Your assertion that the code works on Ideone.com is only true up to a point - it will fail with `n > 25`.